# Getting an error message in writing "tf.io.TFRecordWriter(OUTPUT_IMAGE_TFR)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence

Could anyone please help me in resolving the issues in my code, I can run the code without any issues in Colab however in my local jupyter it pop's up the following error.. `"TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"`

**CODE:**

```
writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(OUTPUT_IMAGE_TFR)

patch = [[]]
cur_patch = 1

for prediction in predictions:
    patch[0].append(tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
    if (len(patch[0])==patch_width*patch_height):
        print('Done with Patch ' + str(cur_patch) + ' of ' + 
        str(patches)+ '...')
        example = tf.train.Example(
            features=tf.train.Features(
                feature={
                    'prediction': tf.train.Feature(
                        int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(
                            value=patch[0]
                        )
                    )
                }
            )
        )

    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    patch=[[]]
    cur_patch +=1

writer.close()
```

---

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_349/248656990.py in <module>
     10             feature={
     11                 'prediction': tf.train.Feature(
---> 12                     int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(
     13                         value=patch[0]
     14                     )

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __index__(self)
   1055 
   1056   def __index__(self):
-> 1057     return self._numpy().__index__()
   1058 
   1059   def __bool__(self):

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to write images to TFRecord format:

```
def image_feature(imageSample):
  feature = {
    'image': bytes_feature(imageSample.tobytes())
  }
  return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

def WriteTFRecord(images, save_directory, fileNumber):
  """ Writes a TFRecord file containing one or multiple training examples """
  with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(save_directory + 'batch-{0:08d}.tfrecords'.format(fileNumber)) as writer:
    for sample in images:
      tf_example = image_feature(sample)
      writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

1. First define image_feature().
2. Open your writer within `with` (automatically opens and closes the stream)
3. write your sample to TFRecord file

`image` is of shape (num_images, height, width, channel), `save_directory` is the path where you want to save and `fileNumber` is a postfix when writing several files.